# classPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring

I am new  at spring framework, I installed spring tool suite 4 .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


       <bean   id="database"  class="springintro.CustomerDal">
           
       </bean>


   

   
</beans>
```

Code:

```
package springintro;




import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  context = 
                new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationCustomer.xml");
        
        CustomerManager manager = new CustomerManager(context.getBean("database",ICustomerDal.class));
        manager.add();
        

    }
       //IoC - Inversion of Control
       //Dependency Injection
       //Spagetti Code
       //SOLID
    
}
```

> // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problems:     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a
> type  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
>
> at springintro.Main.main(Main.java:13) //

Comment: Stop using the old outdated xml configuration. Use java based configuration

Comment: Looks like you miss a dependecy while running your project